# ASP.NET DataSource & GridView databinding, setting a parameter value programmatically

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, objectdatasource

So, I have a GridView with an ObjectDataSource, and I want to programmatically set one of the SelectParameters of the ObjectDataSource.

I tried (during both Page_Load and DropdownList__SelectedIndexChanged)

```
objectDataSource.SelectParameters["my_parameter"].DefaultValue = "my_value";
objectDataSource.DataBind();
```

but it didn't work. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trap the onselecting event on the datasource.

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.InputParameters["month"] = DateTime.Now.Month;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it myself.

In Page_Load:

```
objectDataSource.Selecting += new ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventHandler(objectDataSource_Selecting);
```

Then write the handler method:

```
void objectDataSource_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    int four = 2 + 2;
    e.InputParameters["my_parameter"] = four;
}
```

Then make sure to databind the GridView somewhere

```
protected void dropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```